# Use adb to remove adoptable storage

Tags: adb, samsung, adoptable-storage

I followed [these steps](https://jimcofer.com/2016/03/10/marshmallow-lg-and-adoptable-storage/) (in brief, enable debugging and use adb to enable storage and format sd card) to enable adoptable storage on a Samsung A01 to make the phone more usable (device is not rooted). It basically seemed to work and some apps could be moved to the SD-card and freed up space.

It freed up enough space that I then tried to update the OS (to One UI 3.1 / Android 11) and am now stuck. After the install, most software just hung until I removed the sd card. I have since reformatted the card and uninstalled all the apps previously moved to it and tried the same command sequence hoping to re-enable adoptable storage.

The phone basically works now except the SD card isn't working correctly - I assume it's still looking for the now missing adoptable storage. It complains: "SD card missing" / "insert device again".

I'm wondering if there are similar adb commands to undo adoptable storage - even if the adoptable storage partition is missing. Hoping to avoid a factory reset.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2):

I came back to this and found the magic incantation [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-extend-storage-using-sd-card-space.3614396/page-2):

Basically, connect back to the device and redo the earlier partition command replacing the word "private" with "public". In my case:

```
adb shell sm partition disk:179,64 public
```

Having said that - I then tried to redo the process and am discovering the phone may not play well with adoptable storage. Wonder how many phones get landfilled because of this design issue - all of 2yo.

*Perhaps I spoke a bit too soon...*
Wasted a couple more hours on this and found another nugget on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/cptlui/uncomplicated_functioning_way_to_get_whatsapp_on/): buried in Developer Options is "force allow apps on external" With that I was finally able to free some storage and it seems to work - time will tell. Perhaps leaving this here may be of use to someone.